# Assigning a pointer address to a node

Tags: c++, linked-list

Following is my code for inserting a number in linked list if afterWhat is the number contained in head.
The error comes in the last line of the code where

head -> next = &temp;

The error is :

cannot convert Node** to Node* in assignment.

What I want to do is give the address of temp to the head.next so that head will point to temp.

```
void LinkedList::insertAfter(int toInsert, int afterWhat)
{
       if(head->data == afterWhat)
       {

        Node* temp = new Node;
        temp->next = head->next;
        temp->data = toInsert;
        head->next = &temp;
       }
}
```

Comment: `head->next = temp;`?

Comment: `temp` is already a pointer to a node. Don't you just want `head->next = temp;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since temp is already a pointer,so you don't have to write &temp.
use head->next=temp;

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
head->next = temp;
```

Type of `temp` is `Node*`, so type of `&temp` is `Node**`, so the compiler complains correctly.